# Twitter: ui-metrics from javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

I am trying to build my own Twitter Bot, but I'm stuck at the point where it needs to press a button to continue to the next page. My Page is twitter.com/account/access and when the account is locked it will show javascript on account/access?js=1 with this JS I can obtain the ui_metrics which I need for the next payload. My problem is that I obtain an incorrect UI metrics. The code on account/access?js=1 looks like:

```
      var fioDNpGxgmnkgCviIszx = function() {
    $('.Button').prop('disabled', false);function CzHMSLRaxHitXCjrMvSI() {var aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=228;var a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=234;var a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8=9;var a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=161;aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=~(aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4&aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4);a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428^a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428;a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8=~a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8;aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=function(XSlSY,HCUYy,sLRiq){function ABGhk(lYBbi){this.rbMeE=function(){return this.mQFmd^lYBbi;}};var JutGW={mQFmd:sLRiq};var kVGSg=new ABGhk(XSlSY);kVGSg.mQFmd=HCUYy;ABGhk.prototype=JutGW;return kVGSg.rbMeE()|(new ABGhk(HCUYy)).rbMeE();}(aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4,a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29,a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428);a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=~(a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29&a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8);a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=function(lHUyQ,vsVJI,HSoJI){var FtMNB=document.createElement('div');FtMNB.setAttribute('style','display:none;');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(FtMNB);function RTiPq(xwdds,nrUno){for(var i=0;i<8;i++){var HyJWh=document.createElement('div');xwdds.appendChild(HyJWh);HyJWh.innerText=nrUno;if((nrUno&1)==0)xwdds=HyJWh;nrUno=nrUno>>1;}return xwdds;};function UWDtX(HyJWh,FtMNB,nrUno){if(!HyJWh||HyJWh==FtMNB) return nrUno%256;while(HyJWh.children.length>0)HyJWh.removeChild(HyJWh.lastElementChild);return UWDtX(HyJWh.parentNode,FtMNB,nrUno+parseInt(HyJWh.innerText));};var nrUno=UWDtX(RTiPq(RTiPq(RTiPq(FtMNB,lHUyQ),vsVJI),HSoJI),FtMNB,0);FtMNB.parentNode.removeChild(FtMNB);return nrUno;}(a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29,a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428,a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428);aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=function(SNUeY,wyMcY,jnUNa){var hPVCO=document.createElement('div');hPVCO.setAttribute('style','display:none;');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(hPVCO);function jpszb(dsoIa,gVlrY){for(var i=0;i<8;i++){var kAZuz=document.createElement('div');dsoIa.appendChild(kAZuz);kAZuz.innerText=gVlrY;if((gVlrY&1)==0)dsoIa=kAZuz;gVlrY=gVlrY>>1;}return dsoIa;};function YvUDO(kAZuz,hPVCO,gVlrY){if(!kAZuz||kAZuz==hPVCO) return gVlrY%256;while(kAZuz.children.length>0)kAZuz.removeChild(kAZuz.lastElementChild);return YvUDO(kAZuz.parentNode,hPVCO,gVlrY+parseInt(kAZuz.innerText));};var gVlrY=YvUDO(jpszb(jpszb(jpszb(hPVCO,SNUeY),wyMcY),jnUNa),hPVCO,0);hPVCO.parentNode.removeChild(hPVCO);return gVlrY;}(aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4,a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8,a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8);a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8=~(a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8&a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29);a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=~(a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428&aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4);a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8=function(VtQxq,JDmbe,HodKX){var opBXC=document.createElement('div');opBXC.setAttribute('style','display:none;');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(opBXC);function kGiOS(bmzQA,vkEop){for(var i=0;i<8;i++){var XdtAo=document.createElement('div');bmzQA.appendChild(XdtAo);XdtAo.innerText=vkEop;if((vkEop&1)==0)bmzQA=XdtAo;vkEop=vkEop>>1;}return bmzQA;};function wTYEk(XdtAo,opBXC,vkEop){if(!XdtAo||XdtAo==opBXC) return vkEop%256;while(XdtAo.children.length>0)XdtAo.removeChild(XdtAo.lastElementChild);return wTYEk(XdtAo.parentNode,opBXC,vkEop+parseInt(XdtAo.innerText));};var vkEop=wTYEk(kGiOS(kGiOS(kGiOS(opBXC,VtQxq),JDmbe),HodKX),opBXC,0);opBXC.parentNode.removeChild(opBXC);return vkEop;}(a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8,aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4,aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4);aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4^a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428;aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=function(JGvCJ,CZNEA,ajWfe){var Znwrh=document.createElement('div');Znwrh.setAttribute('style','display:none;');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(Znwrh);function WcTis(SzYNI,TwoYh){for(var i=0;i<8;i++){var LQHaS=document.createElement('div');SzYNI.appendChild(LQHaS);LQHaS.innerText=TwoYh;if((TwoYh&1)==0)SzYNI=LQHaS;TwoYh=TwoYh>>1;}return SzYNI;};function Vukgq(LQHaS,Znwrh,TwoYh){if(!LQHaS||LQHaS==Znwrh) return TwoYh%256;while(LQHaS.children.length>0)LQHaS.removeChild(LQHaS.lastElementChild);return Vukgq(LQHaS.parentNode,Znwrh,TwoYh+parseInt(LQHaS.innerText));};var TwoYh=Vukgq(WcTis(WcTis(WcTis(Znwrh,JGvCJ),CZNEA),ajWfe),Znwrh,0);Znwrh.parentNode.removeChild(Znwrh);return TwoYh;}(aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4,a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8,a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428);aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=~(aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4&aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4);a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428|aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4;a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29|a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428;a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8=a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8&a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8;a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428|a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428;a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29^new Date(a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29*10000000000).getUTCDate();aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4^a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8;a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8=a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8^new Date(a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8*10000000000).getUTCDate();a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=~(a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428&a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29);a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=~a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428;a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29^a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8;aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=function(nEzec,EegJb,rTBen){function ARFVQ(esSLG){this.KVEMV=function(){return this.KkIOD^esSLG;}};var Xopnv={KkIOD:rTBen};var bpsMS=new ARFVQ(nEzec);bpsMS.KkIOD=EegJb;ARFVQ.prototype=Xopnv;return bpsMS.KVEMV()|(new ARFVQ(EegJb)).KVEMV();}(aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4,a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8,aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4);a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=~(a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29&a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8);aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4=aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4|aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4;a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29=function(xZcWJ,PMxhH,qtcNS){var fkXcC=document.createElement('div');fkXcC.setAttribute('style','display:none;');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(fkXcC);function KHNOb(OtqjX,AMEcs){for(var i=0;i<8;i++){var ncNlf=document.createElement('div');OtqjX.appendChild(ncNlf);ncNlf.innerText=AMEcs;if((AMEcs&1)==0)OtqjX=ncNlf;AMEcs=AMEcs>>1;}return OtqjX;};function MseEH(ncNlf,fkXcC,AMEcs){if(!ncNlf||ncNlf==fkXcC) return AMEcs%256;while(ncNlf.children.length>0)ncNlf.removeChild(ncNlf.lastElementChild);return MseEH(ncNlf.parentNode,fkXcC,AMEcs+parseInt(ncNlf.innerText));};var AMEcs=MseEH(KHNOb(KHNOb(KHNOb(fkXcC,xZcWJ),PMxhH),qtcNS),fkXcC,0);fkXcC.parentNode.removeChild(fkXcC);return AMEcs;}(a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29,a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428,a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29);a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428&a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8;a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428=a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428|a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428;a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8=a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8&a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29;return {'rf':{'aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4':aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4,'a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29':a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29,'a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8':a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8,'a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428':a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428},'s':'6rrNTyjkfhoyl3rg2FDTf66srNDiG4KC9a2WZxPhIuYibvxvbr9Ol3yvc_ZwJUEeRVYs_gdMA_wM1tWYenL1FxUF2ssilmw9D78EndVw6p8TWep5o9Yf53DZPG4-2l9yE-fvtPZ4er88FC2-8A65GgxuHtwt7b5M0E8_VjW882MzGUUgxWpJ4hUR7SAZs6vsXyriHQxSmQ6rPo3R1oCRBcRK1qSW9uxQYnex5ks-sXskXKyRsFnRLzpp0Jl5PTTsixiGDl0gI7mkMY38IAVTq_5U21QPuqG6hhFto5x-oA0SMV3y0M6tR0pseWolht3SOTL0u20xLA_MWoqd_XsVQgAAAYMOoR5n'};};
    var zczpQtGKyj;
    try {
      zczpQtGKyj = JSON.stringify(CzHMSLRaxHitXCjrMvSI());
    } catch (e) {
      zczpQtGKyj = "exception " + e;
    }
    var inputs;
      inputs = document.getElementsByName('ui_metrics');
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { inputs[i].value = zczpQtGKyj; }

  }

  var tiIKkHESFDEdobreOyeY = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tiIKkHESFDEdobreOyeY);
    window.removeEventListener('load', tiIKkHESFDEdobreOyeY);
    window.setTimeout(fioDNpGxgmnkgCviIszx);
  }

  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    window.setTimeout(fioDNpGxgmnkgCviIszx);
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tiIKkHESFDEdobreOyeY);
    window.addEventListener('load', tiIKkHESFDEdobreOyeY);
  }
};
yvOyxmAwGvnIARXVXhAk();
```

And the UI-Metrics look like this:

```
{"rf":{"aeb56204b7dfbb714b9f12941a38203fa093e8efdba351010742b86e6a3bd7c4":127,"a749666c3c90c3b92db8140aaf4bf3fdcaaaa9757e148533e0905da43f71fb29":-18,"a0142c051d9b8b9e324e86454560d9578058db0b686d12ac8c99685f9960c9a8":-60,"a67adf5c8e0cc5e48af38fcce933d4ea423490465329dc5804658da386048428":-48},"s":"6rrNTyjkfhoyl3rg2FDTf66srNDiG4KC9a2WZxPhIuYibvxvbr9Ol3yvc_ZwJUEeRVYs_gdMA_wM1tWYenL1FxUF2ssilmw9D78EndVw6p8TWep5o9Yf53DZPG4-2l9yE-fvtPZ4er88FC2-8A65GgxuHtwt7b5M0E8_VjW882MzGUUgxWpJ4hUR7SAZs6vsXyriHQxSmQ6rPo3R1oCRBcRK1qSW9uxQYnex5ks-sXskXKyRsFnRLzpp0Jl5PTTsixiGDl0gI7mkMY38IAVTq_5U21QPuqG6hhFto5x-oA0SMV3y0M6tR0pseWolht3SOTL0u20xLA_MWoqd_XsVQgAAAYMOoR5n"}
```

I made it obtain the text on the account/access?js=1 site and save it to a text file, where I made a function in python that obtains the "ui_metrics"

My code:

```
ui_metrics = ui_metrics_code.split(f'var {split_ui_metrics};')[0].split('return ')[-1].replace(';','').replace('\n','').split("  ")[0].replace("}}","}")
```

(where ui_metrics_code is the response text as above)

which returns in:

```
{'rf':{'d1a4aa70239ad88006075fef748959edb5e520a120c6c2c81d01ab5a85d6d40f':d1a4aa70239ad88006075fef748959edb5e520a120c6c2c81d01ab5a85d6d40f,'adcfa4d4340cd3b32e2d310686e79a56f2825b7eb6c6ce96b322f24423f0847d':adcfa4d4340cd3b32e2d310686e79a56f2825b7eb6c6ce96b322f24423f0847d,'baa9e1c07813efeff769ef29f5ce6864b07dad1bd2c2a472f95e1a9757e5c14c':baa9e1c07813efeff769ef29f5ce6864b07dad1bd2c2a472f95e1a9757e5c14c,'aa71801b588167a6a0e578c9043ce76001f2a66c2543b83081770643da54c04e':aa71801b588167a6a0e578c9043ce76001f2a66c2543b83081770643da54c04e},'s':'au5l9uA05MtyeXy05-64Mca8JuHi-uX7Zj-AhiRRySJa-4oPF-lvFyUSLE7RK8LnZ1w4KjQ-Nnko_cO7_s01h8VorlZcjqDczGw54WZ5UXVPdrHuuM9jmWKwJKZLF-c-GM96fPGPx0jr-S5GatOXfD_awkPI61HDeblfOKGZxqPQkQpTvGpAbcuur2QZr7MRzx5UMgmaZZDYjRqqPgDwWZADV-XBD9csj6lCsdirfNFvkHPQU4SmXwNHn2hZaN-ntfrMIpajcxhBCsX-S2HZpb9F4D6F16JtvVX9giQbm10KRuX3sGCxCy6x02n6p-eIj3f3lvmQxo1Bl23S1A2LZAAAAYMO9BRe'}

as you can see I miss the numbers like :127 and :-18 after the variables.
```

Im trying to understand where these numbers come from and how I can obtain these so I can get a correct UI-Metrics. Im pretty new in all this so im still trying to understand. Help would be really appreciated!

!important : i repost question : 73613573